# Java app - slow run and oversized .exe file

Tags: java

For a few weeks now I'm bashing my head around how to minimize my wrapped java program and make it load and run faster an more reliable. I'm writing a GUI app which iteracts with files and SQL database. Tipically the app is loaded from a network share. When loading the apps JAR it's all instantaneous - no lagging of any sort and the app load time is pretty short.
However when I load the wrapped app (using Launch4j - with embedded JRE - so the PC from which the app is running does not need java installed), the app loads slower. It's around 5 to 10 seconds to load the first screen.
I think that has something to do with the fact that it has to run javaw from the apps JRE path and then through java load  the app. Hense my first question...

Is there a better way to make a java app executable, but not a JAR so the PCs that run the app will not require Java installed.
Also I've noticed that the .exe file is pretty big (around 79MB) and based on what java apps I've seen there should be a way to minimize that. My other theory is that when I load the app from a network share the size of the .exe file cause the delay in loading. I guess I'm right because when I run the app locally in loads faster.
The significant size comes from the jar libraries within the class path, so my second question is born:

What would be the correct way to remove or exclude the parts of a JAR library, that I don't need. Maybe here I must say that I'm using IntelliJ. I'm not using Maven or Jenkins or any other build tool for that matter.

I'm looking forward to learn the stuff that has been bothering me lately. :D
Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help.

Comment: I'd expect the significant size to come from the JRE being bundled. You don't have that when you rely on the existing local JRE to be used. Thus you load less resources through the network. Now: _If_ the network is your problem needs to be measured, not guessed. But if it is, there might be only little tweaks without much effect, as I doubt that you can shrink the size.

Comment: Hi,The JRE is not in the exe file but rather in a directory outside the classpath, so the size defenitely comes from the libs, cuz when I exclude one or two the exe file shrinks significantly. There are similar java apps (not mine), loading from the network that load fast, so the problem is within me.

Comment: If you're using a recent enough version of Java, you could see if [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/jpackage/packaging-overview.html) gives you better results. Or you could try to make a [native image using GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/reference-manual/native-image/).

Comment: My mistake, I'm sorry. It's not embedded it's bundled. Thanks for the advices I'm going to try them ASAP.